# Object rotation without "animation"

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to rotate an object in OpenGL without it spinning on its axis repeatedly. Is there anyway to fix this or do I have to get some other library or something?

I'm just trying to draw some flat squares and rotate them to make a simple 3 walled 1 floor room to test lighting and shadows in.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, what do you mean by "rotate without spinning on it's axis repeatedly"? can you paste some code?

Comment: As you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: This question is almost backwards. First you learn how to rotate something, _then_ you learn how to continually repeat this process to imbue a "spin" effect.

Comment: @Tomalak But if you don't know how to save the current transformation, then continously spinning the objects is much easier.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, if you always change the current matrix and don't know how to revert to a previous state you are always continously transforming an object. His problem is not so much related to a frame to frame animation, but an object to object animation.

Comment: @Christian: OK, but even as a first tutorial step, you'd never push a transformation and not pop it afterwards. You'll overflow your stack pretty fast. The initial approach would be to apply your rotation with a `glRotate*` call, and later learn how to experiment with changing what you pass into that call based on parameters of your program and time.

Comment: @Tomalak The thing is that he didn't push it nor pop it. He probably just sets identity at the start of the frame and then does all transformations. And as said, his problem is not so much related to frame to frame animation (therefore the title is a bit poor), but to object to object "animation" within a single frame.

Comment: @Christian: Well, whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is a bit unclear, it sounds like you are not aware of `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix`. With `glPushMatrix` you can essentially save the currently selected matrix and then restore it again with `glPopMatrix`. But keep sure to follow every `glPushMatrix` with a corresponding `glPopMatrix` somewhere in time. But you definitely don't need to use another library.

So I think you want to do

```
for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(...);
    wall(i);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the transformation on the object.

For example - section 9.020 of [the OpenGL resources pages](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm) has this example:

```
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(90., 1., 0., 0.);
gluCylinder(quad,1,1,2,36,12);
glPopMatrix();
```

This will rotate a cylinder 90 degrees around the X axis